# Where's the "super+a" gone?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

I have a question; when I was using 15.10, by pressing a combination of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> I could see proposals for programs to be installed in the dash, but after upgrading to version 16.04 this key combination does not work. Any idea of how to repair? Unless this option is no longer available?

specifically, I mean:

so it looks like the below given programs installed you have suggestions of programs to install

[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/0520b517dc2bb.png))</sub>

and when you write suggestions:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/03d3a156dbf8d.png))</sub>

and now I have this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/74c4ce3e4fd75.png))</sub>

and suggested:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/234c139203620.png))</sub>

As you can see on the screenshots, there's no guide for programs to install, and it makes me slightly hurt. Why is it screwed up?